Should the build directory generated by a paclet's building process be source controlled?
Should the build/ directory generated by a paclet's building process be source controlled?

The answer is probably no. Have you tried that?

Answering my own question, I decided to not version control the whole subdirectory called 'build' because it contains another snapshot copy of the .m source files for the paclet some files with the file name extension *.paclet which I believe is the built product that's the Wolfram equivalent of *.exe Windows applications.
